# How to find stream order in QGIS 2.18.12?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-processing

In QGIS 2.18.12. I read that using these two commands r.stream.order or v.stream.order one can find stream order. But I am unable to find them in my processing toolbox?

Comment: There is a stream order tool in the SAGA Toolbox. That might be of use.

Answer (score 2):

`r.stream.order` or `v.stream.order` are GRASS tools, however, they do not exist in QGIS and I could not find them in GRASS standalone software. But there is another tool among SAGA tools that can extract [Strahler order](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.3.0/ta_channels_6.html). You can find the tool from `Processing Toolbox -> SAGA -> Terrain Analysis - Channels -> Strahler order`

[image]

Comment: Please check https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/R.stream.*_modules for the GRASS GIS modules related to this topic.